# Rails Database strange behavior for type float

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, mysql2

So I have a model named **Booking**. Booking has_many Installments. Schema for Booking and Installment is as follow:

> Booking(id: integer, booking_price: float, installment_start_date: datetime, no_of_installments: integer, frequency: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

> Installment(id: integer, amount: float, name: string, booking_id: integer, due_date: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

I've added an after_create which creates installments for the **booking** as follow.

```
    def generate_installments
      due_date = installment_start_date
      due_amount = (booking_price / no_of_installments).to_i
      fraction_part = (booking_price % no_of_installments).to_i
      (1..no_of_installments).each do |i|
        name = "Installment #{i}"
        due_amount += fraction_part if i == self.no_of_installments
        installment = self.installments.new(name: name, amount: due_amount, due_date: due_date)
        installment.save(validate: false)
        due_date += self.frequency.months
      end
    end
```

Let's say booking_price = 10000000.0 and no_of_installments = 3.

10 / 3 results in 3333333.33! Creating 3 installments with amount 3333333.33 was causing the discrepancies in the total amount of booking when summed up. So I've used fraction_part to get the remainder and add it to last installment.

For a create request with following params:

> "booking_price": 10000000.0,
> "installment_start_date": "2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
> "no_of_installments": 3,
> "frequency": 2,

This code results in following insert queries in logs:

> INSERT INTO `polaris_installments` (`amount`, `name`, `booking_id`, `due_date`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3333333.0, 'Installment 1', 1, '2021-11-01', '2021-11-24 14:59:48.218205', '2021-11-24 14:59:48.218205')

> INSERT INTO `polaris_installments` (`amount`, `name`, `booking_id`, `due_date`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3333333.0, 'Installment 2', 1, '2022-01-01', '2021-11-24 15:00:08.300229', '2021-11-24 15:00:08.300229')

> INSERT INTO `polaris_installments` (`amount`, `name`, `booking_id`, `due_date`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3333334.0, 'Installment 3', 1, '2022-03-01', '2021-11-24 15:00:32.965686', '2021-11-24 15:00:32.965686')

But when I query the Installments for booking_id 1, I'm getting following results:

```
[#<Installment:0x00007fb497d200e8
  id: 45,
  amount: 3333330.0,
  name: "Installment 1",
  booking_id: 1,
  due_date: Mon, 01 Nov 2021,
  created_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.067353000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.067353000 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Installment:0x00007fb49a859ed0
  id: 46,
  amount: 3333330.0,
  name: "Installment 2",
  booking_id: 18,
  due_date: Sat, 01 Jan 2022,
  created_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.075685000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.075685000 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Installment:0x00007fb49786aa58
  id: 47,
  amount: 3333334.0,
  name: "Installment 3",
  booking_id: 18,
  due_date: Tue, 01 Mar 2022,
  created_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.081846000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:53:46.081846000 UTC +00:00>]
```

Summing the :amount for all installments should be equal to booking_price. But that's not the case.

> 3333330.0 + 3333330.0 + 3333334.0 = 9999994.0
> booking_price = 10000000.0

I'm trying to investigate the cause of this strange behavior. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Look at the Postgres log, I 'm betting `3333333.0` is actually being sent to the database as `3333330.0`. Best bet, the code doing the reapportioning of values in Ruby is not doing what you think it is. FYI, if you are interested in precision use `numeric` not `float`.

Comment: On a side note I would seriously consider moving the creation of installments out into a service object instead of using callbacks as it gives you more control of exactly when it happens (and more importantly doesn't happen) and it lets you pass parameters.

Comment: Also you should not use floats for money. Use decimal or an integer in smallest monetary denominator (cents). "Use numeric" is bad advice since it's the higher class that both floats, decimal and integers inherit from in ruby. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/544825

Comment: `numeric` is the the type in Postgres, how Ruby deals with that is a separate issue. It's moot anyway as the OP switched databases in the question.

Comment: Changing the column type to numeric, fixed my issue. Thank you @all for your suggestions.